# Display a fragment when an item in a listview is clicked

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a listview in a fragment class which gets data from a JSON. So far i was able to show the data in a listview. (here data is NEWS items) .I want to display a detailed page of the news when a particular news is clicked in the listview.

Ex: Listview contains only the title and image of the news. When clicking that listview it should display a detailed version of that particulat news segment. How can i do this?

This is the fragment class that has the Listview.

```
package com.fortuna.cinemalk;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.AdapterView;



import com.fortuna.cinemalk.adapter.LazyAdapter;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.model.BaseElement;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.service.CommonVariable;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.service.JSONServices;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.util.Element;

public class NewsFramgment extends Fragment {

    private GridView gridView;
    private ListView listView;

    private ArrayList<BaseElement> News;
    private LazyAdapter adapter;
    private Activity activity;
    private CommonVariable commonVariable;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_fragment, container,
                false);

        activity = this.getActivity();

        commonVariable = (CommonVariable) activity.getApplication();

        //gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                 int position, long id) {


              android.support.v4.app.Fragment detail = new NewsDetailFragment();
              android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
              fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, detail).addToBackStack("back").commit();
               }
              });



            new BackGround().execute();

        return view;
    }


public class BackGround extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            News = JSONServices.getNewsDescription();
            return null;
        } 



        @Override
        /* check again */
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            commonVariable.setNewsDescription(News);

            adapter = new LazyAdapter(News, activity,Element.NEWS_LIST.getType());

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }


}
```

In the code you'll notice that when a item is clicked it moves to the NewsDetailFragment. And that's the class i want to code now.

PS: my JSON already contains all the details including title,images,description..

UPDATE::   This is my NewsDetailFragment class.  It shows all the news at once not the one i clicked.

```
package com.fortuna.cinemalk;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.AdapterView;



import com.fortuna.cinemalk.adapter.LazyAdapter;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.model.BaseElement;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.service.CommonVariable;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.service.JSONServices;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.util.Element;

public class NewsDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private GridView gridView;
    private View view1;

    private ArrayList<BaseElement> newsdetail;
    private LazyAdapter adapter;
    private Activity activity;
    private CommonVariable commonVariable;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsdetail_fragment, container,
                false);

        activity = this.getActivity();

        commonVariable = (CommonVariable) activity.getApplication();

        view1 = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.list);


        /*gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                 int position, long id) {


              android.support.v4.app.Fragment detail = new TheaterDetailFragment();
              android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
              fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, detail).addToBackStack("back").commit();
               }
              }); */



            new BackGround().execute();

        return view;
    }


public class BackGround extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            newsdetail = JSONServices.getNewsDescription();
            return null;
        } 



        @Override
        /* check again */
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            commonVariable.setTheater(newsdetail);

            adapter = new LazyAdapter(newsdetail, activity,Element.NEWS_DETAIL.getType());

            ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) view1).setAdapter(adapter);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: just pass the index u have used in list and send it through bundle and replace the NewSegement with DetailSegment. Simple

Comment: Can you explain more please. I'm new to android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use following

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
Fragment profileFragment = new MovieDetailFragment();//the fragment you want to show
profileFragment.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentTransaction
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, profileFragment);//R.id.content_frame is the layout you want to replace
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**EDIT**

FragmentTransaction are use to perform actions like adding or removing the fragment i.e when u r replacing/changing the existing layout we perform such transaction to replace the fragments.
Bundles  are the most handly tool that is required to save the changes in data when the configuration changes or to pass the data from one activity to other or to  pass the data between the fragments.[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) read this.

For [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999991/what-is-a-bundle-in-an-android-application) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936675/what-does-bundle-mean-in-android) and the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html). Bundles are very easy to understand.

Hope the edit helps.

Answer (score 0):

i was doing this way...

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_for_accsummary,container, false);
       final FragmentTransaction ft=    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


      //geting resources
    Resources res=getActivity().getResources();
    title=res.getStringArray(R.array.title);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ListView l=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    MyAadapter m=new MyAadapter(getActivity(),R.layout.singlerow, title, icon);//custom adapter
    //title--> array of text to be shown on list    icon-->  array of images to be shown on list     R.layout.singlerow--> tells how single row should appear in list
    l.setAdapter(m);

    l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("in seton","setonclick");

            switch(position){

            case 0: 
                AccSummary frag0=new AccSummary();

            bun.putString("uname",uname);
            bun.putString("sessid",sessid);
            bun.putString("custid",custid1);
            frag0.setArguments(bun);
            ft.replace(R.id.lin2,frag0);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
            Log.i("FragFor", uname);

                break;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------       

            case 1:
                      FromAcc acc=new FromAcc();
                      bun.putString("Name",uname); 
                      bun.putString("sessid",sessid);// key - value pair
                      bun.putString("custid",custid1);
                      acc.setArguments(bun);
                      ft.replace(R.id.lin2, acc);
                      ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                        ft.addToBackStack(null);
                        ft.commit();


            break;
            case 2:break;
            case 3:break;
            case 4:break;
            case 5:ChangepassFrag cf=new ChangepassFrag();
                  bun.putString("uname",uname);
                  bun.putString("sessid",sessid);
                  bun.putString("custid",custid);
                  bun.putString("password",pass);
                 cf.setArguments(bun);
                    ft.replace(R.id.lin2,cf);
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
                    break;

            case 6:   break;
            case 7:break;
            case 8:break;
            case 9:
                   Fragment1 f=new Fragment1();
                   bun.putString("uname",uname);
                    bun.putString("sessid",sessid);
                //  bun.putString("custid",custid1);
                    f.setArguments(bun);
                        ft.replace(R.id.lin2,f);
                        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                        ft.addToBackStack(null);
                        ft.commit();
                break;
            case 10:break;
            }




            }





    });





    return v;
}
```

Comment: What if position order changed?